# Windows crash on Amd radeon hd 6490m driver install

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, crash, amd-radeon

I have an HP dv6 pc, i have two graphic cards : Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 and amd radeon hd 6490m. when I uninstall the amd radeon driver, my pc works fine but when I install it, i reboot my pc then the system crash on the windows 7 logo. My graphic card is KO? how can i diagnose that?

Thank You

Comment: From when you have this issue? After crash can you able to uninstall the driver in safe mode and boot normally?

Comment: Yes it's what I do, in normal screen i have the black screen and nothing after that & in safe mode i can go uninstall or disable the amd driver

Comment: From when this issue started? Have update the OS.

Comment: 5 Days ago, Windows 10 did a critical update and since that date I have this problem with my graphic card AMD. I installed then Windows 7 and I always have the problem with my graphic card amd when I install the driver

Answer (score -1):

Just download driver pack solution.driver pack solution will install any driver(about 15 gb).and then boot windows to safe mode.u can search google to do that.safe mode will disable all third apps,including ur driver

Good luck